# How to replace double quotes from a particular value in JSON string?

Tags: json

please refer the json given below that i get after using **gson.tojson(jsonString)**,all the key values are double quoted

```
{
        "ctid": "78b2aa1e7fb04942bf4b7d4771143f2c",
        "id": "d27aa45cc4df4b62bc8e221b17d485c5",
        "uid": "",
        "msisdn": "9886121212",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "actualAmount": "10.0",
        "currency": "USD",
        "userinfo": "{\"UID\":\"dfjnbfnofnv61\",\"TRANSID\":\"898097261\",\"COTENT_ID\":{\"contentid\":\"3019154\",\"contentname\":\"00000004-TheGameofLifeHD03019154\",\"contenttype\":\"Game\"},\"CP_NAME\":\"FT61\"}"
    }
```

but **my requirement is to remove double quotes only from userinfo value**,
ex given below

```
{
    "ctid": "b561400254a9498791b43e2f1ecb1813",
    "id": "813c04d7dae447ea938794024d0b0f78",
    "uid": "",
    "msisdn": "9886121212",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "actualAmount": "30.0",
    "currency": "USD",
    "version":"v2",
    "userinfo": {
        "CP_NAME": "Gameloft",
        "contenttype": "Game",
        "CONTENT_ID": {
            "contentid": "3019154",
            "contentname": "00000004-TheGameofLifeHD03019154"
        }
    }
}
```

both are valid json,can you please help as how to do it.

thanks

Comment: Your requirement is quite strange. Can you explain about the purpose? If no double quotes, how to separeate content of keys, values?

Comment: you will probably need to modify your exisitng object structure either by create a userInfo object or using a HashMap for userinfo. I would suggest adding code to remove " from user info using regexp as the object seems to be autogeenrated Json

Comment: Why don't you just parse the JSON, remove the quotes from the value (e.g. by parsing the value too) and rebuild the JSON again? That's probably the easiest and safest way since messing with regex here might result in unexpected things.

Comment: since its tagged under java then, parse the json and get the userinfo value and use String replace in java

Comment: @DoNhuVy i had made my question more clear. please refer it.

Comment: @akshayapandey can you suggest regex for it.

Comment: The items in your `userinfo`object have escaped `"`, and is "surrounded" by `"`'s. I.e. it **is** a string and should be quoted. You'll have to extract it and un-escape it first, if you want to make it in to a child object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution that had worked for me.

```
             //first take the jsonResponse
            JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonResponse);
            JsonElement userInfoJsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(paramMap.get("FILTERED_USERINFO"));
            //second remove the key-value(String) pair from json 
            jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().remove("userinfo");
            //third add the json element back as key-value(jsonElement)
            jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().add("userinfo", userInfoJsonElement);
```